# C11 _Generic() - How can I suppress gcc code evaluation (Error check) for selections which are not matching with selector

Tags: c, gcc, c11

P.S.- I have taken int and int * for simplicity purpose, It can also be struct and struct *.

I am trying to implement a macro to copy data present in one variable to other independent of the variable datatype, In the below solution I am using '_Generic' compiler feature.
program 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define copyVar(var,newVar) _Generic((var),int:({memcpy(newVar,(void *)&var,sizeof(int));}),\
        int *:({memcpy(newVar,(void *)var,sizeof(int));}),default:newVar=var)
int main() {
   int data = 2;
   int *copy;copy = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
   copyVar(data,copy);
   printf("copied Data=%i",*copy);
}
```

Program 2:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

    #define copyVar(var,newVar) _Generic((var),int:({memcpy(newVar,(void *)&var,sizeof(int));}),\
                int *:({memcpy(newVar,(void *)var,sizeof(int));}),default:newVar=var)
 int main() {
           int data = 2;
           int *copy;copy = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
           copyVar(&data,copy);
           printf("copied Data=%i",*copy);
}
```

Now problem is, 'program 1' get compiled successfully despite some warning.
But while compiling program 2 gcc throwing error:

> error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand  #define
>   copyVar(var,newVar) _Generic((var),int:({memcpy(newVar,(void
>   *)&var,sizeof(int));}),

and I assume this is due to since _Generic int: selection get preprocessed with one more ampersand

> (void *)&&var

why is gcc evaluates all selection?

Comment: This all seems very wrong. What are you trying to achieve? Why memcpy an int? Why the asymmetry?

Comment: You are copying data into an uninitialized pointer. The casts to void* should not be needed.

Comment: Please try to use more lines and white space on `copyVar` macro. It's very hard to read.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for pointing. forget to add malloc in this sample code. added

Comment: Why `int* copy;copy=` instead of simply initializing `int* copy=...`? Also, you don't need the cast of `malloc` return value.

Comment: @n.m. this is sample code I have pasted defining my problem statement. In my actual implementation Data can be also pointer to the structure or structure itself

Comment: You can assign structures to each other with `=` just like `int`s. There is no need for `memcpy` then either.

Comment: @user694733 what if variable I am passing is a pointer to other structure.

Comment: Assuming you have 2 pointers to structures (type `struct S *a, *b`), you can simply do `*a = *b;`.

Comment: @user694733 that is just swapping address of the struct. My intention is to copy data pointed by 'b' into new memory pointed by 'a'

Comment: No, `a = b` would copy address (type `struct S *`) from `b` to `a`. By dereferencing pointer with `*` you get access to pointee. Thus `*a = *b` copies the type `struct S`, from address pointed by `b` to address pointed by `a`.

Comment: @user694733 Yes it's coping whole structure. I was under impression *a will only copy the first member of strut. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has various problems: you copy data into an uninitialized pointed, you have superfluous void* casts, you treat `_Generic` as some sort of compound statement instead of an expression, and so on.

But to answer your question, your code doesn't work because the result of `&something` is not a lvalue. Since the `&` operator needs a lvalue, you cannot do `& &something`. (And you cannot do `&&something` either because that gets treated as the && operator by the "maximum munch rule".)

So your code doesn't work for the same reason as this code doesn't work:

```
int x;
int**p = & &x;
```

gcc tells you that `&x` is not a lvalue:

> lvalue required as unary '&' operand

---

EDIT - clarification

This `_Generic` macro, like any macro, works like pre-processor text replacement. So when you have this code in the macro:

```
_Generic((var), ...
int: ... (void *)&var
int*: ... (void)var
```

It gets pre-processed as

```
_Generic((&data), ...
int: ... (void *)& &data
int*: ... (void)&data
```

And all paths of the `_Generic` expression are pre-processed. `_Generic` itself is not part of the pre-processor, but gets evaluated later on, like any expression containing operators. The whole expression is checked for syntactic correctness, even though only one part of the expression is evaluated and executed.

Comment: Where/why does the extra & appear? The intention seems to be that `copyVar(&data,copy);` selects the `int *:({memcpy(newVar,(void *)var,sizeof(int));})` part, where there's only one &

Comment: Yes as @nos commented. extra '&' is in the first selector 'int:' but that should not have to evaluated for program 2

Comment: `_Generic` is not an `if` or `switch`, it is an expression. I've added a clarification to the answer.

Comment: @user694733 Right, bad choice of words. Fixed, thank you.

Comment: `The whole expression is checked for syntactic correctness` this explains the behavior I am seeing. is it possible to skip this check? since that expression is not going to be evaluated.

Comment: @HardikPanchal you can introduce a temporary named pointer before invoking the macro `copyVar`, and pass it instead of the rvalue expression `&data`.

Comment: @HardikPanchal You could call different functions depending on type. That's usually how I use _Generic myself.

Comment: @Lundin, exactly this was what I was writing down in my answer while your comment came in.

Answer (score 1):

The indented original use of `_Generic` is with function pointers as here

```
#define copyVar(var,newVar) \
     _Generic((var),        \
        int:    function1,  \
        int*:   function2,  \
        default:function3)(&(var), &(newVar))
```

Here the generic expression chooses the function and then this function is applied to whatever are the arguments.

You would have to write the three stub functions that correspond to the three different cases.

If you have them small and nice and as `inline` in your header file, the optimizer will usually ensure that this mechanism does not have a run time overhead.

Comment: Yes @Jens this can be one neat solution. But my actual program has hundreds of structure so I am trying to explore other generic possibilities in C.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a two level _Generic

```
#define copyVar(var,newVar) \
    _Generic((var), \
    int  :   ({  __auto_type _v = var; memcpy(newVar, (void *) _Generic((_v), int: &_v , int *: _v)  , sizeof(int));}) , \
    int *:   ({  __auto_type _v = var; memcpy(newVar, (void *) _v                                    , sizeof(int));}) , \
    default: newVar=var \
)
```